# How do i expand an nested odata table

Tags: odata

I am unable to expand a nested table that I can navigate to in Excel or PowerBI. For example,

Entity set is a list of schools. One column contains a nested table for students that attend the school.

When listing the schools I get the list of school names.  When I add $expand=students i get a list of school names with another column students but each row displays just [] as if there aren't students in the nested table.

https://view.mycompany.com/odata/Schools  --- provides list of schools

https://view.mycompany.com/odata/Schools?$expand=students  --- only provides list of schools and adds the students column without expanding the table.

Comment: Do you know how to do this? I do not see an answer yet?