# odata: How do I expand an nested ICollection of items using $expand in Odata using .net core 3.1

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, odata, linq-to-entities, expand

OData url:
https://{{baseUrl}}/api/vehicles?$expand=OwnershipHistories

I want to return a vehicle(s) and than $expand the OwnershipHistories as a List of owner ship histories.

But I only get one (1) Ownershiphistorie.
Question: **Why can I not get all the ownership histories???**

I have this on my controller:

```
        [HttpGet]
        [EnableQuery(PageSize = 10, MaxExpansionDepth = 20)]
        [ODataRoute("vehicles")]
```

I use this url: {{baseUrl}}/api/vehicles?$expand=OwnershipHistories

I use the following c# code ():

```
public async Task<IQueryable<VehicleEntity>> GetVehicles()
{
    var vehicles = _context.Vehicles;  // .Include(v => v.OwnershipHistories) => ??? Is not working...

    return vehicles;
}
```

The result is:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://localhost:5001/api/$metadata#Vehicles(OwnershipHistories())",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "registrationNumber": "10STNV",
            "vehicleIdentificationNumber": "JF1BP9LLA6G052053",
            // more fields
            "**OwnershipHistories**": [ ?????? Only **one** record, not the **8** records I expect  ?????)
                {
                    "VweID": 1,
                    "registrationNumber": "10STNV",
                    // more fields
                }
            ]
        },
}
```

This is the query for the database:

I have two entities and they are views in the sql database:

```
OwnershipHistoryEntity:
    [Table("EigenaarsHistorie", Schema = "Voertuig")]
    public class OwnershipHistoryEntity
    {
        [Key]
        public int VweID { get; set; } // VDNI
        // more fields
        public virtual VehicleEntity Vehicle { get; set; }
    }
```

VehicleEntity:

```
namespace VWE.MijnVWE.Vehicle.Api.DAL.Entities
{
    [Table("VoertuigInformatie", Schema = "Voertuig")]
    public class VehicleEntity
    {
        [Key]
        public int VweID { get; set; } // VDNI
        public string Kenteken { get; set; }
        public string VoertuigIdentificatieNummer { get; set; }
        // more fields
        [ForeignKey("VweID")]
        public ICollection<OwnershipHistoryEntity> OwnershipHistories { get; set; } = new List<OwnershipHistoryEntity>();
    }
}
```

EdmModel builder:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Builder;
using Microsoft.OData.Edm;
using VWE.MijnVWE.Vehicle.Api.DAL.Entities;

namespace VWE.MijnVWE.Vehicle.Api.BLL.Builders
{
    public static class ModelBuilder
    {
        private static IEdmModel _edmModel;

        public static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
        {
            return GetExplicitEdmModel();
        }

        static IEdmModel GetExplicitEdmModel()
        {
            if (_edmModel == null)
            {
                var modelBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();

                var vehicles = modelBuilder.EntitySet<VehicleEntity>("Vehicles");
                var ownershipHistories = modelBuilder.EntitySet<OwnershipHistoryEntity>("OwnershipHistories");

                modelBuilder.Namespace = "vwe.mijnvwe.vehicle";
                modelBuilder.ContainerName = "vehicleApiContainer";

                vehicles.EntityType.Name = "vehicles";
                vehicles.EntityType.HasKey(k => k.VweID);
                vehicles.EntityType.HasMany(v => v.OwnershipHistories);
                vehicles.HasManyBinding(v => v.OwnershipHistories, "OwnershipHistories");

                ownershipHistories.EntityType.Name = "ownershipHistories";
                ownershipHistories.EntityType.HasKey(k => k.VweID);
                ownershipHistories.EntityType.HasRequired(o => o.Vehicle, (o, t) => o.VweID == t.VweID);

                vehicles.EntityType.Property(p => p.VweID).Name = "id";
                vehicles.EntityType.Property(p => p.Kenteken).Name = "registrationNumber";
                vehicles.EntityType.Property(p => p.VoertuigIdentificatieNummer).Name = "vehicleIdentificationNumber";
// more fields
                ownershipHistories.EntityType.Property(p => p.Kenteken).Name = "registrationNumber";
                ownershipHistories.EntityType.Property(p => p.EventDatum).Name = "eventDate";
                ownershipHistories.EntityType.Property(p => p.SoortAansprReferentieCode).Name = "liabilityReferenceCode";
                ownershipHistories.EntityType.Property(p => p.RegistratieDatumAansprakelijkheid).Name = "from";
                ownershipHistories.EntityType.Property(p => p.RegistratieDatumAansprakelijkheidTot).Name = "to";
                ownershipHistories.EntityType.Property(p => p.DagenInBezit).Name = "numberOfDays";
                ownershipHistories.EntityType.Property(p => p.DatumGewijzigd).Name = "changedDateTime";

                _edmModel = modelBuilder.GetEdmModel();

            }

            return _edmModel;
        }
    }
}
```

Ef core modelBuilder:

```
   public class VehicleDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public VehicleDbContext(DbContextOptions<VehicleDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        { }

        public DbSet<VehicleEntity> Vehicles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<OwnershipHistoryEntity> OwnershipHistories { get; set; }
// more fields
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
// ...
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }
    }
```

This is the Select query:

```
SELECT [t].[VweID], [t].[AandrijvingOmschrijving], 
//more fields.. [t0].[SoortAansprReferentieCode], [t0].[c0]
FROM (
    SELECT TOP(@__TypedProperty_3) [v].[VweID], [v].[AandrijvingOmschrijving], [v].[AantalAangedrevenAssen], 
// more fields 
[v].[Werkingsbeginsel], [v].[Wielbasis]
    FROM [Voertuig].[VoertuigInformatie] AS [v]
    ORDER BY [v].[VweID]
) AS [t]
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP(@__TypedProperty_1) @__TypedProperty_2 AS [c], [e].[VweID], [e].[DagenInBezit], [e].[DatumGewijzigd], [e].[EventDatum], [e].[Kenteken], [e].[RegistratieDatumAansprakelijkheid], [e].[RegistratieDatumAansprakelijkheidTot], [e].[SoortAansprReferentieCode], CAST(1 AS bit) AS [c0]
    FROM [Voertuig].[EigenaarsHistorie] AS [e]
    WHERE [t].[VweID] = [e].[VweID]
    ORDER BY [e].[VweID]
) AS [t0]
ORDER BY [t].[VweID], [t0].[VweID]
```

It is quit similar to the following question:

- [Same question about washington school odata question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67198810/how-do-i-expand-an-nested-odata-table)
- [Washington school code odata example](https://github.com/hassanhabib/ODataDemo)

Comment: The example (https://github.com/hassanhabib/ODataDemo/blob/master/WashingtonSchools.Api/Models/School.cs) School has a collection of students as top level of response.  You do not have a collection of Vehicles as top level.

Comment: Thank you for your response. What can i do in the project to get school/$students. Then maybe I can fix my own problem.

Comment: But it is not possible to do school/$expand=students. Students is null. So I do not know how your answer can help me. Or am I mistaking?

Comment: Why is vehicles not top level?

Comment: You are using two methods 1) Entity which is using dbContext 2) Controller which is parsing the received http response from a server.  I think what you are trying to do is to query a database at the server and get the dbContext and then send the dbContext to a client in a response using a controller.  It looks like the query of the database is going into this line :  public DbSet<VehicleEntity> Vehicles { get; set; }.  You then have to send the list of vehicles in a post to the client.